# com.google.gms:google-services Compatibility Issue with Firebase plugins

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Trying to get an old project up to date today, I ran into an issue (on Android) which I believe has to do with one of the Firebase plugins.
I keep on getting the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Here is a snippet from my pubspec file to show the plugins in my project:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.18
  firebase_storage: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.7.4
  firestore_helpers: ^2.0.5
  image_picker: ^0.2.0
  location: 1.1.6
  flutter_webview_plugin: 0.0.9+1
  font_awesome_flutter: 4.7.2
  flutter_map: ^0.0.1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
```

This snippet shows the project in its current state, with all the new versions for the Firebase products.
I did also update my `build.gradle` files of course, they look like this atm:

*Android level build.gradle file:*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*App level build.gradle file:*

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withInputStream { stream ->
        localProperties.load(stream)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.test.tester"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        profile {
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I believe that is all that I had to do according to the docs, but perhaps I missed something.
Any one an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: remove `firestore_helpers: ^2.0.5` and try building it again

Answer (score 0):

open [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), this contains the list of Firebase libraries versions that you need to use

Comment: But that is something the plugin does I believe: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/android/build.gradle I do not believe that is the problem.