# cloud_firestore and firebase_auth compatiblity issue in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am developing a Flutter app. My app works fine with `cloud_firestore` and `firebase_auth` packages when I use them separately. However, when I include both of them together in my `pubspecs.yaml` file, the build fails and the following message is shown:

> *Note: /home/saber/Code/mobile_dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   Note: /home/saber/Code/mobile_dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.18/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: /home/saber/Code/mobile_dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.18/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   Note: /home/saber/Code/mobile_dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.2.5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.*

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Here are the depenencies that I have in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   firebase_auth: ^0.5.18
   cloud_firestore: ^0.7.4
```

I checked the version of packages and they both seem to be at the latest version.

Any help on resolving this issue would be appreciated!

This might be connected to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803658/com-google-gmsgoogle-services-compatibility-issue-with-firebase-plugins) issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in your android/app/build.gradle file?

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes, I have already added this to my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 6):

Update your gradle version. I was facing the same issue,i have solved it by using below steps.

Step 1:
in app/build.gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ****multiDexEnabled true****

    }
```

Step 2:
change gradle version dependencies in android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Step 3:
 latest version of firebase_auth and cloud_firestore in pubspec.ymal

```
 cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+6
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.2
```

Answer (score 6):

For me work just change the minSDKVersion to 23 in the app build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow this [setup:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

Open android/app/build.gradle and add at the bottom of the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and in the android/build.gradle add the following:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // ,,,
  }
  dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' 
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have already followed this setup. Note that each of the packages works fine when I use it individually. I only get the error when I add both packages to the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use only this dependencies in android/build.gradle and remove any other dependencies

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

You have to use this versions in pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: 0.5.11
google_sign_in: 3.0.4
cloud_firestore: 0.7.3
```

Because these versions have updated gradle tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Following update should resolve the issue:

Update ***android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties***

to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`

and update the dependencies and versions

in ***android/build.gradle***

to  `dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`

and  ***android/build.gradle*** yet

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
```

in ***pubspec.yaml***

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1 
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.11
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade your gradle in app/build.gradle
2. run flutter pub upgrade to get latest dependencies !